# Traveling on two passports with different surnames

Tags: air-travel, passports, dual-nationality, south-african-citizens, greek-citizens

I hold dual citizenship with South africa and Greece. I am currently staying in greece and want to travel to South africa for a holiday and return to Greece. My South african passport has my married surname, and my greek one my maiden surname because they don't change surnames in greece due to marriage.
Which passport name do I book my return ticket under?

Comment: Have you applied correctly for authorization of dual-citizenship in SA?

Comment: I have both passports by birth. I was born in South africa and my parents are greek.

Comment: According to https://www.sahc.org.au/citizenship/Dual_Citizenship.htm in terms of the South African Citizenship Act it is an offence for a South African citizen with dual citizenship to enter or depart the Republic of South Africa making use of the passport of another country. See suggested duplicate question, case 2, which I think addresses your situation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: Since you **legally** have two passports in different names, and a **very common** explanation, there should be no problem. As usual, show the passport of your destination on the trip there, to extablish your right to enter, and show the other passport on the way back.